# Replace jquery ui-icon with a local image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a context menu in which i am adding stuff on the fly. I also want to display icons on my menu using the jquery ui icons styling because it adjusts itself nicely over the jquery menu. I currently have added a clock icon. But I want to replace it with my own image while still using the jquery ui icons styling. How can I do that? Here is the code in which I am adding the icon and other text to my menu:

```
var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var attr = $("<a>", {"class": "textStyle",
            title : itemData.name,
            html : itemData.name
        }) 
        var item = $("<li>")
            .append(attr);
        if (itemData.name=='concepts') {
            attr.append($("<i>", {"class":"ui-icon ui-icon-clock"}))}
        if (itemData.children) {
            var subList = $("<ul>");
            $.each(itemData.children, function () {
                subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
            });
            item.append(subList);
        }
        return item;
    };
```

Comment: Em... Changing class and define the class with CSS?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery Ui icons.css  [cdn link](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css%22%20/%3E)

use this class :

```
.ui-icon-clock:before {
content: "\e023";!important
}
```

And replace your image with  content.
you may try adding background as well with other proper styling.

======Updated======== :

Define a style yourself, like this:

```
.ui-icon-custom { background-image: url(images/custom.png); }
```

Then just use `.ui-icon-custom`  when replacing

This assumes that your custom icon is in the images folder beneath your CSS...the same place as the jQuery UI icon map typically is. When the icon's created it gets a class like this: `class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom"`, and that `ui-icon` class looks like this (maybe a different image, depending on theme):

```
.ui-icon { 
  width: 16px; 
  height: 16px; 
  background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); 
}
```

So in your style you're just overriding that background-image, if needed change the width, height, etc.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. When I do this I am just seeing a 'up' arrow on the menu instead of the clock but not my image. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Salman I have updated the answer, It's working fine for me.Have a look

Comment: Where are you defining the style? In your own seperate css file or in jquery-ui.css? I am defining it in jquer-ui.css, but not getting the desired result. Also where do you create the .ui-icon body?

Comment: It is defined in `jquery-ui.css` itself.
Would you Mind posting your `jquery-ui.css` file?
It should Work

Comment: here is the File Which contains Images as well as styles
have a look: https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip

Comment: I downloaded jquery-ui-1.10.4 folder and added the custom icon style in the jquery-ui.css file.

Comment: Is it Working for you?